# Extract domain name values from OU path powershell

Tags: powershell

I am extracting the OU value from a csv and getting the DC name from it

```
    $TOD_Data= @(Import-Csv -Path "C:\data.csv")
    $OU = $TOD_Data.oupath
    $DC = ($OU -split '(?<![\\]),' | Where-Object { $_ -match '^DC=' }) -join ','
```

the output I am able to extract the values like below

```
DC=ab,DC=if,DC=csg,DC=net
```

But I need to convert this value like this

```
ab.if.csg.net
```

Please let me know how can I do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the [function defined in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71799057/1331399) which parses the DN to a hash, e.g.:

```
$h = $OU | Parse-DistinghuishedName 
$h.DomainComponent -join '.'
```

Or without an intermediate variable:

```
($OU | Parse-DistinghuishedName).DomainComponent -join '.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the function `Split-DistinguisedName` in my `PoshFunctions` module in the Powershell Gallery you could get your answer by the following:

`((Split-DistinguishedName -DistinguishedName $dn -Token | Where { $_ -match '^DC=' } ) -replace '^DC=', '' ) -join '.'`

For a further sample:

```
$dnsample = 'CN=SampleUser,OU=users,DC=subdomain,DC=contosco,DC=com'
((Split-DistinguishedName -DistinguishedName $dnsample -Token | Where { $_ -match '^DC=' } ) -replace '^DC=', '' ) -join '.'

subdomain.contosco.com
```